# finding page load time using selinium getting error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seli.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

following Selenium Java code might help you to find the time for a page load -

```
**long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
driver.get("Some url");
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);**
```

If this does not work then you will have to wait till some element is displayed on the page -

```
**long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
driver.get("Some url");
WebElement WE = driver.findElement(By.id("ID of some element on the page which will load"));
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);**
```